# Modifying AtBeginSection in a Beamer presentation

Tags: beamer

I'm pretty new to TeX, as I used to code with very basic commands. But, in order to pump up a beamer, I looked after a way to display the title of the current section, and the summary for this section, at the beginning of every sections.

I founded the following code :

```
\AtBeginSection{
  \begin{frame}
  \vfill
  \centering
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=8pt,center,shadow=true,rounded=true]{title}
    \usebeamerfont{title}\insertsectionhead\par%
  \end{beamercolorbox}
  \vfill  
  \tableofcontents[currentsection]
  \end{frame}
}
```

It's working pretty for me so far, but I have a few questions :

- How does `\vfill` work exactly? I tried to remove them, but the difference was rather subtle...
- What is `\par`? Removing it doesn't change anything...
- How could I display only the subsections of the current section? As my beamer is a bit long, I actually can't put all of the parts and subparts on one frame, but removing all the subparts from it make it look awkward...
- Is there any LaTeX course that can be recommanded to me?

Thanks in advance for any help/tips!

Since I'm not a native speaker, I may have done a few mistakes. Please forgive me... :|

Answer (score 2):

> - How does \vfill work exactly? I tried to remove them, but the difference was rather subtle...

vfill is a space which will expand depending on how much space there is on the page. If you already have problems to fit your whole toc on the page, I think it it is safe to assume that the page is already rather full, so there won't be much unoccupied space. This means vfill won't have much room to expand, this you don't see a large effect. Also assuming your are using the default centre positioned frames, beamer automatically adds a vfil at the top and bottom of the frame, so any effect you might see from vfill will be distributed between at least 3 places, this making it even less noticeable.

> - What is \par? Removing it doesn't change anything...

`\par` is a macro to start a new paragraph. You can instead also leave an empty line. You need it at the end of the section title, otherwise the linespread of multiline sections titles might be wrong

> How could I display only the subsections of the current section? As my beamer is a bit long, I actually can't put all of the parts and subparts on one frame, but removing all the subparts from it make it look awkward...

You can show just the toc of the current section with `\tableofcontents[sections=\thesection]`. As you already show the current section title right above, you can remove it from the toch with `\setbeamertemplate{section in toc}{}`

> Is there any LaTeX course that can be recommanded to me?

If you want to learn beamer, have a look at the [beamer user guide](https://texdoc.org/serve/beamer/0), it has a rather extensive tutorial at the start

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\AtBeginSection{
\begingroup
  \setbeamertemplate{section in toc}{}
  \begin{frame}
  \vfill
%  \centering
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=8pt,center,shadow=true,rounded=true]{title}
    \usebeamerfont{title}\insertsectionhead\par%
  \end{beamercolorbox}
  \vfill  
  \tableofcontents[sections=\thesection]
  \end{frame}
\endgroup
}


\begin{document}
    
\section{sec1}
\subsection{sub1}
\begin{frame}
    abc
\end{frame} 

\subsection{sub2}
\begin{frame}
    abc
\end{frame} 

\section{sec2}
\subsection{sub21}
\begin{frame}
    abc
\end{frame} 
    
\end{document}
```